# Why is this C linked list program giving 'segmentation fault'?

Tags: c, linked-list

The first function reads a file that has a bunch of 'char's and puts them in a linked list. It is not working :(.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list {
    char val;
    struct list* next;
};

typedef struct list element;

int lcreate(char* fname, element* list);
int ldelete(element* list);
int linsert(char a, char b, element* list);
int lremove(char a, element* list);
int lsave(char* fname, element* list);



int lcreate(char* fname, element* list) {
    element* elem = list;
    char c = 0;
    FILE * file = NULL;

    file = fopen(fname, "r");

    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if(list == NULL) {
            list = (element*)malloc(sizeof(element));
            if(list == NULL) {
                return 0;
            }
            list->val = c;
        }
        else {

            elem->next=(element*)malloc(sizeof(element));
            elem = elem->next;
            elem-> val = c;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    elem->next = NULL;
    return 1;
}



int main(void) {
    int i = 0;


    element * list = NULL;
    lcreate("list.txt", list);

    for(i = 0; i<4; ++i) {
        printf("%c", list->val);
        list = list->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Fixed problem with 'file' being null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One obvious problem is right here:

```
FILE * file = NULL;

fopen(fname, "r");
```

For the `fopen` to accomplish much, you need to assign the result from `fopen` to your `FILE *`:

```
file = fopen(fname, "r");
```

Edit: Since you're working in C, you can't pass the pointer by reference. As an alternative, you can pass a pointer to a pointer:

```
int lcreate(char *fname, element **list) {

     // ...
     *list = malloc(sizeof(element));
     (*list)->next = null;
     (*list)->val = c;
// ...
}
```

Basically, all the code inside of `lcreate` will need to refer to `*list` instead of just `list`. Alternatively, you can take a pointer to an existing list as input, and return a pointer to the list, so in `main` you'd have something like: `list = lcreate("list.txt", list);`

Comment: And don't forget that `elem= list` assigns a value. If you want `elem` updated when `list` is updated you need to change `elem` to `element **elem= &list` in the original code or `element **elem= list` in Jerry's version.

Answer (score 2):

`file` is `NULL`, and you never assign a file handle to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yep -- what the others said about the `FILE` pointer, and passing `list` by value rather than reference to `lcreate()`, is true.

You also aren't returning the size of the list from `lcreate()` -- you should probably return this via the return value or a pointer argument.

You are attempting to iterate through the list 4 times in the `main()` function, but there may be less than 4 items in the list.  Eventually the `printf()` will cause a segmentation fault if `list` is NULL.

If you still have issues after making these changes, I would recommend adding tracing to your code to work out at which point the segmentation fault is happening.

**Update:**

Also please remember to free the memory you have allocated after you traverse the list, otherwise you'll end up with a memory leak (although in practice this won't really be an issue for you as the program is ending, but freeing memory is a good habit to get into).

Answer (score 1):

In your `main` function, you are also passing `list` by value to `lcreate`. Within the `lcreate()` function, you are overwriting a local copy of `list`, not changing the value of `list` in the main function. Since `list` is initialized to `NULL`, you will get a segfault when you call `list->val`.

Comment: Ok so how do I overwrite list in lcreate? Thanks!

Comment: @ron - Pass in a double pointer to `list`, i.e.  `element** list; lcreate("list.txt", list);`.  Then in the `lcreate` method, you allocate it like this: `*list = malloc(...)`.  This will ensure that the caller will see the changes made by the callee.

Answer (score 0):

I can see an additional problem as well. In the while statement of `lcreate()` the true clause of the if statement malloc's some memory and assigns it to `list` however `elem` is not updated.

```
while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
{
    if(list == NULL) {
        list = (element*)malloc(sizeof(element));
        if(list == NULL) {
            return 0;
        }
        list->val = c;
    }
    else {
```

Next time through the while loop `list` will not be non-null but `elem` is still null so  the assignment of elem->next tries to deference the null pointer and thus the segmentation fault (which, btw, means that you tried to access memory that has not been assigned to your process):-

```
else {
    elem->next=(element*)malloc(sizeof(element));
```

As others have pointed out you also don't return `list` back to main so it will still be NULL when you hit the printf() loop.

Finally, the debugger is your friend when looking at these problems. You'll see exactly which line triggers the seg fault and what the state of the variables were.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to check if the malloc was successful by checking for a non null pinter. 
Also, you might want to allocate the head/first link outside of the while to avoid the null check for the head every time in the while loop. Of course, these are optimizations, in case your linked list grows really large!