# why can't we pass the pointer by reference in C?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

I am learning C. I was writing code to create a linked list when i came across a segmentation fault. I found a solution to my problem in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293033/why-is-this-c-linked-list-program-giving-segmentation-fault) question.
I was trying to pass a pointer by reference. The solution says that we can't do so. We have to pass a pointer to a pointer. This solution worked for me.
However, I don't understand why is it so. Can anyone tell the reason?

Comment: Because there are no references in C. Do you need reason for why there are no references in C?

Comment: The language doesn't support passing objects by reference. Simple as that.

Comment: You *can* pass pointers to pointers, though, but they're still passed by value.

Comment: In C *everything* is pass-by-value (I can almost smell the flame jets warming up with that statement). If you want to have a caller-side modifiable parameter, the "value" you pass must be the address of the thing-to-modify, and the formal parameter must be declared as a pointer to that type (even if its a pointer, in which case it would be a pointer-to-pointer). Even arrays are pass-by-value, it just happens the "value" per the standard for an array as an expression is the address of its first element. But its still a *value* (one that give you access to hit up the callers var, admittedly).

Comment: Perhaps this post will also help you to understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963269/can-someone-explain-how-pointer-to-pointer-works/23964156#23964156    Basically, in order to manipulate where a pointer points, you must have it's address.  The address of an object -is- a pointer to an object.  Hence, passing the address of a pointer (ie: a pointer to a pointer) will allow the called function to change where the pointer points.

Comment: In C++ a "reference" is also a pointer, its just not visible to the outside. So if you pass a pointer in C (or a pointer to a pointer in your case) it's the same code as in C++ passing a rerfernce, only the syntax differs.

Comment: And internally the only difference between a pointer and a reference in C++ is that the pointer can be dangling, can be NULL, but a reference always, well, "refers" to an existing object.

Comment: @LaszloLadanyi Really? Can't I dereference a `NULL` or dangling pointer and pass that as a reference? The effect would be the same...

Comment: I stand corrected. This code compiles, and segfaults...
`
int main()
{
int *pi = 0;
int &ri = *pi;
ri=5;
return 0;
}
`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From *The C Programming Language - Second Edition*  (K&R 2):

> **5.2 Pointers and Function Arguments**
>
> Since C passes arguments to functions by value, there is no direct way
>   for the called function to alter a variable in the calling function.
>
> ...
>
> Pointer arguments enable a function to access and change objects in
>   the function that called it.

If you understand that:

```
void fn1(int x) {
    x = 5; /* a in main is not affected */
}
void fn2(int *x) {
    *x = 5; /* a in main is affected */
}
int main(void) {
    int a;

    fn1(a);
    fn2(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

for the same reason:

```
void fn1(element *x) {
    x = malloc(sizeof(element)); /* a in main is not affected */
}
void fn2(element **x) {
    *x = malloc(sizeof(element)); /* a in main is affected */
}
int main(void) {
    element *a;

    fn1(a);
    fn2(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, there is no difference between an `int` and a pointer to element, in the first example you need to pass a pointer to `int`, in the second one you need to pass a pointer to pointer to element.

Comment: You seem to be quoting some source (start of you answer). Would you mind mentioning this source?