# Why can't I access to the located memory?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

The program read a data from a file to an array, `load_data` loads the data to the array `ar`. However why do I get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` when I access that array in the `main`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
long int load_data(double * ar);

int main(void)
{
    long int n,i;
    double * ar; 
    FILE * fp; 
    double number;

    n=load_data(ar);

    fp = fopen("data-copy.txt","w");
    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        fprintf(fp,"%lf\n", ar[i]); //problem here! I can't access!
    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    fclose(fp);

    printf("The number of elements in the file is:%ld\n",n);
}

long int load_data(double * ar) 
{
   FILE * fp; 
   double temp;
   long int n=0,i;

   fp = fopen("data.txt","r");
   while(fscanf(fp,"%lf",&temp)==1)
       n++;
   fclose(fp);
   //load memory
   ar = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);

   fp = fopen("data.txt","r");
   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
       fscanf(fp,"%lf",ar+i);
   //    printf("%lf\n",ar[i]);//This print well!
   }
   fclose(fp);

   return n;
}
```

Comment: You are passing `ar` by value. So the `ar` in `main` is different then the `ar` in `load_data`. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052243/why-cant-we-pass-the-pointer-by-reference-in-c).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I thought this is very similar to an array. For array I am passing it by address... Thanks, I am going to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the program listing below - I have modified your code so that you send the pointer to the pointer ar... this works perfectly now. @Johnny Mopp's comment is perfect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
long int load_data(double ** ar);

int main(void)
{
    long int n,i;
    double * ar; 
    FILE * fp; 
    double number;

    n=load_data(&ar);

    fp = fopen("data-copy.txt","w");
    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        fprintf(fp,"%lf\n", ar[i]); //problem here! I can't access!
    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    fclose(fp);

    printf("The number of elements in the file is:%ld\n",n);
}

long int load_data(double ** ar) 
{
   FILE * fp; 
   double temp;
   long int n=0,i;

   fp = fopen("zdata.txt","r");
   while(fscanf(fp,"%lf",&temp)==1)
       n++;
   fclose(fp);
   //load memory
   *ar = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*n);

   fp = fopen("zdata.txt","r");
   for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
       fscanf(fp,"%lf",*ar+i);
   //    printf("%lf\n",ar[i]);//This print well!
   }
   fclose(fp);

   return n;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! works great!

Answer (score 1):

All function arguments in C are pass by value.

Your `main` function *copies* the value of `ar` (a garbage value) to wherever the compiler puts function arguments (usually in specified registers or on the stack).

In the function `load_data` the copy of `ar` is changed to a pointer to a block of memory *but the original `ar` in `main` is unchanged* and is still garbage.

When you exit the function, you throw away the copy of `ar` (leaking the malloc block).  Then you try to dereference the original `ar` which is still garbage.